# MySQL prevent user to take codes from other user

Tags: php, mysql

Hello have the following query:

```
SELECT code FROM tbl_codes WHERE used='0' ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 2;
```

This will result in 2 codes with unique value (ex: code = 1 code = 2). After that I will update the table that those codes are used with following query:

```
UPDATE table_codes SET used='1', mail_at=NOW(), user='1' WHERE (code='1' OR code='2') AND used='0';
```

My question is how to prevent that another user get the same 1 or 2 codes of the first user? The 2 codes can only assigned to 1 user.

Users can get 2 tickets for an event. The 2 codes will be send by mail as barcode to scan at the event.

Comment: If you have already assigned the codes to a user (`user = '1'`) and also set them to expired (`used = '1'`), then how can they be used again if you're checking for only unexpired codes `... WHERE used='0'`? Maybe I'm missing something. Can you explain a bit more about the retrieving/assigning scenario?

Comment: @Matt, sometimes multiply user getting the same codes during the query,  when the flag used is not set to 1, I want to prevent that. Users can get 2 tickets for an event. The 2 codes will be send by mail as barcode to scan at the event.

Comment: You'll want to do both queries within a transaction, and the `SELECT` needs to become a `SELECT ... FOR UPDATE`.

Comment: @Patrick, so you mean with a row lock, get following query in queue other codes then, if the lock is released?

Comment: I can't really understand what you're asking, but this will prevent the selected rows from being selected again until they have been updated and the transaction is committed.

Comment: I can't see the need for a transaction. Just omit the SELECT. Then the lock is automatic.

Comment: @Strawberry  I'm assuming OP wants to actually use the code somewhere, aside from just marking it used, but I could be wrong.

Comment: @Patrick Yes you are right, must send the 2 codes by mail as a barcode. What I mean is the when the rows are marked as used and not committed and another user fires the same query he gets new codes or an error message?

Comment: @Martijn  The use of `RAND()` complicates things a bit, as it will actually result in a table lock, rather than a row lock.  If you're okay with that (additional queries to that table will wait until the open transaction completes), then no big deal.  If you're dealing with a high-volume application though, that may not be suitable. You might want to read the discussion on this question/answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14203537/mysql-how-to-achieve-row-level-transaction-locking-instead-of-table-locking

Comment: @ Patrick, just what I need, good answer on that question. Will try it.

Comment: I think another option would be to put your two queries in a loop.  If the `UPDATE` doesn't actually update any rows (because those codes no longer satisfy the `used='0'` condition), go back through the loop and pick new codes. If the `UPDATE` _does_ update rows, then you know it is safe to mail out the selected codes.

Comment: FYI, what you're dealing with here is a "race condition" if you want to do some general research on the topic

Answer (score 0):

```
UPDATE table_codes 
   SET used = 1
     , mail_at = NOW()
     , user = 1
 WHERE used = 0 
 ORDER 
    BY RAND() 
 LIMIT 2;
```

Comment: This will not work, because I need to send the 2 codes in an email as barcode.

Comment: Hm, changing the parameters of the question.